# HTML input time, step attribute to set timestep by (say) x minutes?

Tags: html, input

I have a time input, basically just:

```
Time: <input type="time" name="timeinput"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8E9N/

According to 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html
it supports the step attribute.  Is it possible to use this attribute (or other means) to set the step size to 10 minutes?  If so, how?

I am aware of some other solutions (e.g. datebox plugin), but I'm hoping for a purely html solution if possible.  I am using the datebox plugin sometimes, but it seems pretty slow on mobile devices so I am trying to use the native time pickers when possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. [You can specify step attribute in seconds](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#time-state-%28type=time%29).

However, Opera, iOS Safari, and Google Chrome don't reject non-aligned user input. A user can specify 11:59 to such time field. Then, Opera and Google Chrome show a validation error message when he tries to submit the form.

Answer (score 15):

It's possible. You just need to put seconds in step parameter, ex.

```html
<input type="time" step="300"> <!-- 5 min step -->
```

Comment: I don't see the 5 minutes step in the input type

Comment: @AravindReddy you can't see the step because this is no longer supported, you probably have to create your own.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like Chrome 86 does not support this.

Comment: Indeed. It seems like the new (and much nicer!) time input no longer supports the step attribute.

Comment: Yeah, without stepping, I had to create my own.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 9.1, iOS doesn't support max min or step.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime