# Is it possible to filter html5 input time list

Tags: html

I would like to filter the list appeared after clicking on an input time. For example, for the minutes I would like to show only 0 or 30

[image]

```
<input type="time" step="30" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input time, step attribute to set timestep by (say) x minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713755/html-input-time-step-attribute-to-set-timestep-by-say-x-minutes)

Comment: There is really nothing you can do to adjust the rendering of it. Might be simpler to just use a select element.

Comment: +1 ^, Also, if you wish to have custom time picker it's better to use some jquery/javascript library which creates picker for you and then you can customize that..

Answer (score 0):

You can't only show each half hour, but if you have the step in a form, HTML will take into account the step in the validation.

However, the step is in seconds, so you want `30*60 = 1800`

```
<input type="time" step="1800" />
```

[image]