# Step attribute does not work in <input type="datetime-local"> and <input type="time">

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I can't understand the step attribute in `<input type="datetime-local">` and `<input type="time">`. It seems to be badly implemented in all major browsers.

#### Step="1", steps every 1 second as expected

As you can see by running the code snippet bellow, wen we set step to 1, the time is shown in seconds, not minutes (step is defined in seconds).

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step=1>
<input type="time" step="1">
```

#### Step="60", steps every 1 minute as expected

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step=60>
<input type="time" step="60">
```

So far, so good!

#### Step="600", ... what just happened?

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step=600>
<input type="time" step="600">
```

Am I crazy or should one expect that the input would show only options in steps of 600 seconds (10 minutes)? Maybe it only works when you pass from seconds to minutes and then to hours, let's see

#### Step="3600", ... not what I expected ... but wait!?

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step=3600>
<input type="time" step="3600">
```

Have you noticed that the minute part of the time is "off"? It kind of suggests that minutes are disabled as it is expected in steps of 1 hour.

### Summing up

To sum up, this is all very strange. What am I missing here?  Input of date and time is something basic, why should one need to implement it in javascript?

P.S. ----
I know... I know... others have asked this before in SO ([Step Attribute doesn't work for HTML input type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64806765/1344369)). But I didn't see a definitive answer and I wanted to expand the question showing this different step values. I think it is quite strange that in Chrome steps="3600" changes the color of minutes.  Don't get me started about Safari...

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="datetime-local">` is boring, it's just change step if you press arrow-up or arrow-down on your keyboard. It's don't show you step you want.