# Second does not show on html input with type="datetime-local" and step="1"

Tags: html

I can't get the second to display in the input field even with type = "datetime-local" and step = "1", but it displays with type = "time". I have tried multiple browsers including Chrome, Edge, Firefox, etc on Android.

It can be reproduced in the first test box in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73409234/step-attribute-does-not-work-in-input-type-datetime-local-and-input-type-t) as shown below:

[image: no second shown with datetime-local]
[image: second shown with time]

What have I done wrong? How can I have the input in the datetime-local box show seconds?