# Customising input type="time" in HTML

Tags: html, input, time

Is there a way to customise the the times selection dropdown that is opened from HTML input type="time"?
I want to show the minutes column every 5-min (00,05,10...55) and not every 1-minute as it's used for the default behaviour (see screenshot)

[input type="time" example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlCLP.png)

Comment: There is no way of changing the UI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713755/html-input-time-step-attribute-to-set-timestep-by-say-x-minutes